# Scrapy: How to pass a response url to cmdline parse to overwrite local source path

Tags: python, parsing, cmd, scrapy

In order to scrape responsefully and don't put too much load onto a server, I first download web pages using `:~$ scrapy fetch "http://some.tld/page" >> some.tld-page`. Secondly, I'm testing my spider using `:~$ scrapy parse --spider=some_spider "file://~/some.tld-page`".

When accessing `response.url` within the spider's `parse()` method, it contains the local file uri (`file://../some.tld-page`). Is there any possibility to overwrite this by a custom URL?

Comment: aren't you passing that in the command line?

Comment: @eLRuLL Do you mean there is a cmdline argument? If yes, which one? I'm passing the local file uri as I don't want to put unnecessary load on the server all the time. But my `parse()` method uses `urlparse.urlparse(response.url)` to check whether a certain url path is present or not, e.g. whether the path equals `/page`. The local file uri doesn't contain a path, query string or a fragment, so that's the reason I would like to *emulate* a real response url.